# Trouble counting occurence of values between 3 connected columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am having tremendous difficulty in getting around a Power BI function.

I am super new to Power BI and I've learned a lot already but I'm still confused about some topics.

I uploaded some data from excel into my Power BI applicaiton and it had some data as such.

Returns (Tab 1)

Order ID (column 1)

1

2

3

Orders (Tab 2)

Order ID (column1)          Product ID (column 2)

1                                       100

1                                       101

2                                       101

3                                       101

3                                       100

4                                       100

Product (tab 3)

Product ID (column 1)           Product(column 1)

100                                         Table

101                                         Chair

What I am trying to do is figure out the top 5 products that are returned.

I know the data above only has 2 products, but the actual data in my Power BI file has many more.

I basically want to take the Order ID from tab 1, compare them with the multiple product ID's each order has in tab 2 and then compare that with the product names in tab 3 to figure out the top 5 products that are returned.

I've already establihed all the relationships and linkages.

I've tried to use the "Top N", count distinct and sum functions but I was unable to get the filteration mechanism to work properly.

I kept on getting the total number. I also tried using matrix but that didn't work either.

You can access the file with this[link][1] in case anyone wants to look at the data I am working with to get a better idea of my problem. Page 3 is where majority of my attempts have been at trying to solve the problem.

I'm basically trying to find the top 5 most returned products, ideally in a graph and maybe using a slicer.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnMQvyG3G5w6iTcKZUaBvA_oLalv

That link above leads to the download page to downloads the PBIX file I am working with.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: You have some inactive relation between tables in your model. Do a double check as may be they are impacting your output. Also please clear your desired output. If I guess correct, you wants TOP 5 product (Based on count) per ORDER ID. Is that correct? Please include a screenshot/picture of your desired output as well if possible. This will help it understand better.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I double checked the relatonships but it seems all the relevant ones reagrding the ID's and names are connected with each other.

Comment: can you show your final output in a table visual you are expecting?

Comment: Sure, use this link (https://imgur.com/a/qpYgTYf). The ideal output is the graph on the right, the table is just to show the raw data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a **Table** using this below **DAX**-

```
minimum_return_show = 

VAR return_per_product_name =  
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(  
   Products[Product Name],
    "return", count(Products[Product Name])  
)

var top_n =  
MINX(
    TOPN( 
        5,
        return_per_product_name,
        [return]
    ),
    [return]
)

return 
TOPN(
    1,
    FILTER(
        return_per_product_name,
        [return] >= top_n
    ),
    [return],
    ASC
)
```

Now create a **Measure** as below-

```
product_count = 

if(
    count(Products[Product Name]) >= max(minimum_return_show[return]),
    count(Products[Product Name]),
    0
)
```

**Finally** create your bar chart using column **product_name** and measure **product_count**. Apply filter on **product_count** with **greater than 0** and hopefully you will get your desired output.